# Does an ETH purchase on a CEX result in creation of a Tx on the ETH network?

Tags: transactions

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the nuts and bolts of Ethereum, and I understand that every simple ETH transfer from an EOA to an EOA requires a Tx. But I also now realize that Ethereum currently has a max TPS of about 15. I'm still trying to wrap my mind around how a worldwide system like this can get anything done with that low of a throughput, and one of the immediate questions that jumps to mind is all the buying/selling of ETH that occurs on exchanges.

Does an ETH purchase on a CEX (such as Binance) result in creation of a Tx on the ETH network, or do they handle this internally somehow (staying completely within the CEX software) without touching the Ethereum network? (I know that transferring ETH off the exchange to your own wallet such as Metamask requires a Tx)

Answer (score 1):

No, any trade of an exchange is internal and does not appear on the blockchain, hence why it's defined as centralized.

Decentralized exchanges (DEXs), such as Uniswap, happen on the blockchain.